# React-admin: How to omit Create view when using CloneButton?

Tags: react-admin

Is there any possible way to omit Create/Edit view when using CloneButton imported from CloneButton?

What I expect:
Simple clone record by pressing button, without any Create/Edit form views and confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the CloneButton in this case but make a custom one which will get the current record by calling the `useRecordContext` [hook](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Architecture.html#context-pull-dont-push) and will make the API call by calling the mutation function returned by the [`useCreate`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#usecreate) hook.